# IOS how to get live latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation

I want the current latitude and longitude of my device. I can print latitude and longitude when my program locate the device for the first time but I can't refresh it.

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    int lastindex = [locations count]-1;

    CLLocation * currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:lastindex];

    float latitude =currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;

    float longitude =currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"LAT:%f LONG:%f",latitude,longitude);

    [self latitudeLabel].text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"latitude : %@",[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitude] stringValue]];

    [self longitudeLabel].text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"longitude : %@",[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:longitude] stringValue]];

}
```

This is what I tried but latitude/longitude are never updated. I tried it with the function didUpdateHeading but that didn't work either.

How can i do this. Any one can help me to solve this issue.
Thanks you

Comment: Irrelevant to your issue, but you can use `[locations lastObject]` to get the last location instead of computing the index every time. Also, you don't need to `alloc` your strings- you can just do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"...` to save a little coding going forward. Also, why convert your `float` to an `NSNumber` and then to an `NSString`, when you can just use the `%f` like you do in your `NSLog`?

Comment: I did some treatment with my float but I dont need it anymore you are right thanks you

Answer (score 1):

This method is triggered by `startUpdatingLocation` which I assume you're using since it did get called at least once. The method gets called each time the location data changes. Is your location actually changing enough to trigger it? Also, check the `distanceFilter` property on your `CLLocationManager` and make sure it is low enough.

Comment: yes I call >startUpdatingLocation. The distanceFilter is set to >kCLDistanceFilterNone and the desiredAccuracy to >kCLLocationAccuracyBest.
When i go back from the navigation controller and call my view again the latitude and longitude is different. I want my labels are updated because at the moment the user have to reload the view to get the current position.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the following to your header:

```
@interface YourLocationObject : SomeObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

.. and when you create your CLLocationManager object, you set yourself as the delegate:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
//... other customization here ...//
[locationManager startUpdatingLocations];
```